# Is there anything wrong with this sentence: "My class sizes range from 10 to 50 students coming from diverse background"?

Tags: grammar

Is there anything wrong with this sentence:

"My class sizes range from 10 to 50 students coming from diverse background"?

Comment: Make `background` plural - *diverse* implies more than one.

Comment: Stand up for lost causes **!** Say "...from ***divers*** backgrounds," instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Background" should be plural because each of the 10-50 students would have his or her own background.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been stated by Lawrence, diverse implies more than one.  The sentence needs the article (a) in front of diverse.  Using the plural form of background would also suffice.